# Чем грозит использование кириллицы в URL? (ЧПУ)

Tags: php, чпу

Является ли хорошим тоном использование в адресной строке кириллицы? Начал колдовать над сайтом с использованием ЧПУ, не знаю, обязательно ли транслитерировать русскоязычные названия страниц?

Comment: Например, ХэшКод активно использует кириллицу в URL!

Comment: вот такими вот ссылками при копировании оных:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/246356/php-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-url-%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83

но не во всех броузерах.
ЗЫ: Модераторы, не нужно редактировать эту запись :)

Comment: [Гугль по сабжу](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+%D0%B2+URL). Как видите, ничем страшным это не грозит.

Comment: Хорошо. Какой вариант оптимальней - латиница или кириллица?

Comment: @shurik, почему не только в вашем комментарии, но и в адекватной литературе я вижу "броузер", вместо "брАузер"?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/2665/deus потому, что слово Browser читается как Браузер, можно ещё русское слово использовать - обозреватель, оно так переводится.

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, ну,так я об этом же ж! Наоборот, спрашиваю, почему пишут "брОузер" как в комментарии выше. (((

Comment: @shurik а как по-русски будет web-programmer? (С учётом того, что William -- Уильям)

Comment: @alexlz, во первых "web-programmer" не употребляется, либо употребляется очень редко, обычно это web-programmist или web-developer, во вторых так и будет, Веб-программист (Веб-разработчик). Учет крайне не корректный, потому что в слове William совсем другая словоформа, поэтому и читается оно по другому.

Comment: @shurik спорить не буду, поскольку изучал немецкий, но в словарях транскрипция приводится одинаковыми буквами William ['wɪljəm], web -- [web]. Ну, а судя по вопросам начинающих web-developer'ов на этом сайте, Ваше утверждение не кажется истинным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уголовным кодексом. А если серьёзно то соглашусь с комментарием. Сейчас активно использует google, hashcode. Но как по мне, латиница - это классика.